# Слово категории состояния? Наречие? Что это?

Tags: морфология, части-речи, наречия

Скажите пожалуйста, какая часть речи **«видно»** в этом предложении:

> Хотя неба мне не было **видно**, но по тому, как хмурился лес, я
>   чувствовал, что над ним тихо поднимается тяжелая туча.

Просто **«видно»** может быть и словом категории состояния выражая физические ощущения человека или других живых существ: больно, душно; видно, слышно.
Но это может быть и наречие! Так что же это?

И еще одно: в предложениях ниже **«приятно»** это слово категории состояния или наречие?

> 1) Здесь будет **приятно** работать!
>   2) Она никогда не была ему другом.
>   Но ее участие было **приятно**.

Мне кажется, что в 1-ом – **наречие**, потому что относится к глаголу, а во 2-м - **слово категории состояния** – обозначает психич. состояние…я права?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) Хотя неба мне не было видно. Предикативное наречие относится к  категории состояния (значение зрительного восприятия). В функции обстоятельства образа действия, как обычное наречие, не употребляется.

2) Здесь будет приятно работать! Категория состояния.

3)  Но ее участие было приятно. Краткое прилагательное.

Answer (score 1):

Наречие относится к глаголу и в предложении выступает в роли обстоятельства. В вашем примере "видно" предикатив. Видно - состояние, физическое ощущение человека.
...было приятно. Краткое прилагательное,выполняет функцию сказуемого в предложении.

Чтобы отличить краткие прилагательные в функции сказуемого,следует помнить следующее:

> прилагательное выполняет функцию сказуемого в предложении с подлежащим, а имя состояния в безличном предложении, т.е. без подлежащего.
>   Прилагательное согласуется с подлежащим в роде и числе, т.е. изменяется.
>   Прилагательное обозначает признак предмета.

Но ее участие было приятно.

Участие подлежащее, прилагательное -приятно,обозначает признак предмета(участие),выполняет функцию сказуемого в предложении с подлежащим, согласуется с подлежащим ***участие*** в среднем роде единственного числа, на что указывает окончание -о .